# Confusing component pin spacing info in datasheet

Tags: datasheet

this is part of datasheet from Vishay. I want to do a footprint based on this picture, but can't figure out the dimensions...

The space between the pins is described two times: is says 0.220 (5.6) and 0.180 (4.6) at the same time. I just don't get it. Thanks for help.

[image: bridge]

Answer (score 7):

The dimensions are maximum and minimum. Basically the actual dimension will be somewhere between the two.

For your footprint I would take the dimensions for pin locations to nominally be the mid point.

As pointed out by @Trevor in the comments, for the size of the holes, take the maximum dimension and add on any drill tolerance to ensure the holes are large enough.

Comment: +1 but for holes you need to take the max dimension then add the max tolerance on the drill to find the right hole size. Obviously for square section leads you need to use the diagonal.